# Is the right-shift operator in Objective C on OSX/iOS an arithmetic or logical right shift?

Tags: objective-c, ios, macos

Is the right-shift operator in Objective C on OSX/iOS an arithmetic or logical right shift?

I can't find any references that specify whether the right-shift is arithmetic or logical, or if it varies depending on the data type (signed/unsigned) and/or architecture (x86/PPC/x64/ARM).

"Programming in Objective-C 2.0" states that this is effectively undefined, but that conflicts with information I've seen elsewhere that compilers attempt to "do the right thing" based on signed-ness of types.

Comment: Objective-C is a superset of C... So look in the C standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a quick experiment in the iOS simulator, with the following fragment:

> ```
> int i = -600;
>
> for (int j = 0; j < 68; j++)
> {
>     NSLog(@"j: %d i: %d", j, i);
>     i = i >> 1;
> }
> ```

Which yielded the result:

> j: 0 i: -600
>
> j: 1 i: -300
>
> j: 2 i: -150
>
> j: 3 i: -75
>
> j: 4 i: -38
>
> j: 5 i: -19
>
> j: 6 i: -10
>
> j: 7 i: -5
>
> j: 8 i: -3
>
> j: 9 i: -2
>
> j: 10 i: -1
>
> j: 11 i: -1
>
> ...

This would seem to indicate that the shift is arithmetic, not logical, because the sign of the answer is preserved.

Comment: Which compiler did you use? There are 3 options, and since the behavior is implementation-defined, they might behave differently.

Comment: I got the same result though with GCC 4.2 and with Apple LLVM 2.1, though

Comment: Not terribly surprising. The logical shift is the more sensible way to resolve this bit of implementation-defined behavior, and it also makes sense that LLVM copied GCC's decision. But it's still important to know which compiler you're using ;)

Answer (score 5):

Objective-C does not define the behavior for the right-shift operator. That operator is defined in C. Here's the relevant part of the ANSI C spec:

> The result of **E1 >> E2** is E1 right-shifted **E2** bit positions. If **E1** has an unsigned type or if **E1** has a signed type and a nonnegative value, the value of the result is the integral part of the quotient of **E1 / 2^E2**. If **E1** has a signed type and a negative value, the resulting value is implementation-defined.

So yes, right-shift operator on a negative number is implementation-defined according to the spec.

Comment: +1, except that it's implementation defined, not undefined.  The compiler implementation does have to make a choice and document it.

Comment: @Carl: Fair point, but I would argue that compilers have to make choices about how to handle undefined behavior as well, so "undefined" and "implementation-defined" within the spec are roughly equivalent terms.

Comment: @Kevin - they absolutely don't have to make choices about undefined behaviour.  For instance, if you were to use `>>`, it will either *always* be sign-extending or always *not* be sign-extending (well, for two's complement, anyway), whereas if you do `p = p++`, you could get a different answer every time.  There is a very real difference between undefined behaviour and implementation-defined behaviour.

Comment: @Carl: Ok, I concede the point. I will edit my answer to use "implementation defined" instead.